# Meaning of 'bar a scrap' in "Squaw" by Bram Stoker

Tags: meaning, short-stories, bram-stoker

> "Wall!" he said, "I guess I've not had enjoyment like this since 
>   I left Noo York. **Bar a scrap with** a French sailor at Wapping-an' that 
>   warn't much of a picnic neither-I've not had a show fur real pleasure 
>   in this dod-rotted Continent, where there ain't no b'ars nor no 
>   Injuns, an' wheer nary man goes heeled. Slow there, Judge! Don't 
>   you rush this business! I want a show for my money this game-I du!"

The above paragraph is from 'Squaw' by Bram Stoker. The phrase 'bar a scrap with' seems to me 'to fight with someone', but I am not so sure, since there is no specific explanation in dictionary as to 'bar' to the extent that  'picking a fight or similar context'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Bar" means "except for," "with the exception of."

"I guess I've not had enjoyment like this since I left Noo York. [Except for] a scrap with a French sailor at Wapping-an' that warn't much of a picnic neither."

"Bar" in this sense is still widely used.